# How to create a process in Dell Boomi that will get data from one Database and then will send data to a SaaS

Tags: api, connector, boomi

I would like to know how do I create a process in Dell Boomi that will meet the following criteria:

1. Read data directly from Database poduction table then will send the data to SaaS (public internet) using REST API.
2. Another process will read data from SaaS (REST API) and then write it to another Database table.

Please see attached link as to what I have done so far and I really don't know how to proceed. Hope you can help me out. Thank you.[Boomi DB connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKYsw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually making a good start. For the first process (DB > Saas) you need to:

1. **Ensure you have access to the DB** - if your Atom is local than this shouldn't be much of an issue, but if it is on the Boomi Cloud,
   then you need to enable access to this DB from the internet (not
   something I would recommend).
2. **Check what you need to read and define Boomi Operation** - from the image you have linked I can see that you are doing that, but not
   knowing what data you need and how it is structured, it is impossible to say if you have defined all correctly.
3. **Transform data to the output system format** - once you get the data from the DB, use the Map shape to map it to the Profile of the Saas you are sending your data to.
4. **Send data to Saas** - you can use HttpClient connector to send data in JSON or XML (or any other format you like) to the Saas Rest API

For the other process (Saas > DB) the steps are practically the same but in reverse order.